# Visual Basic loop removing the last character

Tags: vb.net

I have just started to learn Visual Basic and I am having trouble with a loop. What I want it to do is print out the string `"ABCDEFG"` into a list box then remove the last character and print it out until only `"A"` is left.
This is the code I am using:

```
Dim abc As String = "ABCDEFG"

For i = 0 To 5
    abc.Substring(0, abc.Length - 1)
    lstabc.Items.Add(abc)
Next i
```

The desired result would look like this but all i get is lines of `"ABCDEFG"`

> ABCDEFG
>   ABCDEF
>   ABCDE
>   ABCD
>   ABC
>   AB
>   A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never assigning anything different to abc, so it's always adding the full string. Also, you are not specifying a different length to substring. Try this.

```
Dim abc As String = "ABCDEFG"
Dim abc_alt as String
For i = 0 To abc.Length - 1
    abc_alt = abc.Substring(0, abc.Length - i)
    lstabc.Items.Add(abc_alt)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

String in c#, vb.net are non mutable. So you need to store the result in another variable and print that variable.

```
  Dim substr As String 
  substr = abc.Substring(0, abc.Length - i)
  lstabc.Items.Add(substr)
```